# Vue - Remove listener when value in vuex store changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a component for my darkmode settings that looks like this:
[image]

Automatic - Takes the settings from the OS
Light - Applies a light theme overriding OS settings
Dark - Applies a dark theme overriding OS settings

**What goes wrong**
Currently when i switch to either 'light' or 'dark', and then start changing the preferred color scheme in my windows settings, it still keeps switching to whatever I select over there. This should be ignored when the setting is ***not*** automatic.

**What i think is happening**
I guess the `eventListener` still exists, and should be destroyed when a user selected 'light' or 'dark'. I tried doing with a `AbortController()` but had no success.

**app.vue**
In my app.vue i watch the current settings and if it's 'automatic' i set an initial theme and have an `EventListener` that  picks changes up from the OS.

```
  created() {
    this.$store.watch(
      (state) => {
        return state.settings.colorSettings.automatic;
      },
      (currentAutomaticValue) => { 
        if (currentAutomaticValue) { //if automatic is true
          if (
            window.matchMedia &&
            window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches
          ) {
            document
              .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
              .setAttribute("theme", "theme-dark");
          } else {
            document
              .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
              .setAttribute("theme", "theme-default");
          }
          window
            .matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
            .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
              const darkMode = e.matches ? true : false;
              document
                .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
                .setAttribute(
                  "theme",
                  darkMode ? "theme-dark" : "theme-default"
                );
            });
        }
      },
      { immediate: true }
    );
```

**switchComponent.vue**
Here i run a function when the selected value changes. This functions looks like this:

```
methods: {
    onSwitch(event) {
      if (!this.colorSettings?.loading) {
        switch (event.target.id) {
          case "automatic":
            this.colorSettings.automatic = true;
            break;
          case "light":
            this.colorSettings.darkMode = false;
            this.colorSettings.automatic = false;
            break;
          case "dark":
            this.colorSettings.darkMode = true;
            this.colorSettings.automatic = false;
            break;
        }

        this.$store.dispatch("setDarkMode", this.colorSettings);

        document
          .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
          .setAttribute(
            "theme",
            this.colorSettings.darkMode ? "theme-dark" : "theme-default"
          );
      }
    },
  }
```

**Settings.js state**

```
import { SettingsService } from "@/api/settingsService";

const state = {
  colorSettings: {
    loading: false,
    automatic: true,
    darkMode: false,
    colors: {}
  }
};

const getters = {
  loadingColorSettings: state => {
    return state.colorSettings.loading;
  },
  colorSettings: state => {
    return state.colorSettings;
  }
};

const mutations = {
  SET_COLOR_SETTINGS(state, colorSettings) {
    state.colorSettings.automatic = colorSettings.automatic;
    state.colorSettings.darkMode = colorSettings.darkMode;
    state.colorSettings.colors = colorSettings.entityTypeColors;
  },
  SET_LOADING_COLOR_SETTINGS(state, isLoading) {
    state.colorSettings.loading = isLoading;
  }
};

const actions = {
  setDarkMode: (context, updatedDarkmode) => {
    context.commit("SET_LOADING_COLOR_SETTINGS", true);
    SettingsService.setColoring(updatedDarkmode)
      .then(response => {
        context.commit("SET_COLOR_SETTINGS", response.data);
      })
      .catch(resp => {
        console.error(resp);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        context.commit("SET_LOADING_COLOR_SETTINGS", false);
      });
  }
};

export ...
```

Anyone can give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: What is the value of `response.data` in `commit('SET_COLOR_SETTINGS', response.data)`? Can you share a link to a reproducible example (e.g., in Codesandbox)?

Comment: I would refactor your code if i could get my hands on it.
I would try to use the @click events that Vue offers, and "watch" the changes in your vuex store via computed properties in the component.

Comment: The problem with doing it in the component like that is that the changes don't happen on routes where the component isn't in right? When the setting is on 'automatic', i want it to happen instantly when the user changes it in it's OS. I posted an answer below that works for now, if you have any feedback on that please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

*I suspect the problem is not the watcher, but it's difficult to tell with the code shown in question. Assuming the active watcher is the problem...*

The `$watch()` call returns a function that removes the watcher, so you could use it in your callback when `currentAutomaticValue` is falsy:

```js
export default {
  created() { 
    const unwatch = this.$store.watch(
      (state) => {
        return state.settings.colorSettings.automatic;
      },
      (currentAutomaticValue) => {
         if (currentAutomaticValue) {
           //...

         } else {
           // no longer need to watch
           unwatch() 
         }
      },
      { immediate: true }
    )
  }
}
```

This has a caveat in that if you need to re-enable the watcher, you'll have to create a new one, so I recommend moving this watcher setup from `created()` into a method that could be called when needed.

Comment: I tried something like this, but didn't get the re-enabling part. So i tried removing only the `EventListener`, and now it works (see my answer below), needs work but it's a start. Thanks for your effort! If you have any suggestions for optimizing my answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So removing the `EventListener` apparently works after all. I tried to do this before but didn't get it to work then.

Code needs optimization **(suggestions are very welcome!)**, code looks very messy. But this is a start.

**What i did:**

- Made a seperate function `setTheme()` for the listener so that i'm able to remove it
- Had to put `window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")` in a constant, this was also needed to be able to remove it
- Remove the listener when the watcher sees that `currentAutomaticValue` is false

  ```
   methods: {
    setTheme(e) {
      const darkMode = e.matches ? true : false;
      document
        .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
        .setAttribute(
          "theme",
          darkMode ? "theme-dark" : "theme-default"
        );
    }
  },
  created() {
    const media = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

    this.$store.watch(
      (state) => {
        return state.settings.colorSettings.automatic;
      },
      (currentAutomaticValue) => {
        if (currentAutomaticValue) {
          if (
            window.matchMedia &&
            window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches
          ) {
            document
              .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
              .setAttribute("theme", "theme-dark");
          } else {
            document
              .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
              .setAttribute("theme", "theme-default");
          }
          media.addEventListener("change", this.setTheme);
        } else {
          media.removeEventListener("change", this.setTheme);
          if (this.colorSettings.darkMode) {
            document
              .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
              .setAttribute("theme", "theme-dark");
          } else {
            document
              .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
              .setAttribute("theme", "theme-default");
          }
        }
      },
      { immediate: true }
    );
  }
  ```